# i delete an image and caching in android but again app shows it to me

Tags: android, image, caching, download

i have items in one recyclerview and when i download it with HttpURLConnection library and save that item that have image and it correctly save in my phone.
when i delete that item from my phone in my app it will be deleted both descriptions and image correctly

if i save that item with another image but the same name for image i saw that it shows me the first image that i have saved before even after i deleted that.

I have no code to cache my image but i have a code to clean cache folder
i have tested that code and it cleans cache folder but i have that problem yet.
in debugging i saw that the cache folder is empty because "for" is not run and directly the cache foler is deleted

is there any folder except cache folder that my android save image for caching?

Downloading Image Code:

```
private Bitmap downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream iStream = null;
    File secondFile;
    Bitmap.CompressFormat format = null;
    try {
        File myDir = AdapterContext.getFilesDir();
        String Extention ="png"
        File NewsDirectory = new File("my app location and folder");
        if (!(NewsDirectory.isDirectory() && NewsDirectory.isDirectory())) {
            boolean success = (new File("check if folder is not made then it make it")).mkdir();
        }
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
        secondFile = new File("my app folder"+"my file name" + Extention);
        ImageAddress = secondFile.toString();
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(secondFile);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
        bitmap.compress(format, 85, outstream);
        byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();
        stream.write(byteArray);
        stream.close();
        ImageDownloaded = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Delete caching code:

```
File dir = Context.getCacheDir();
deleteDir(dir);
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
String[] children = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
if (!success) {
return false;
}
}
return dir.delete();
} else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
 return dir.delete();
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys my problem was solved with this code below just befor connection was open:

```
UrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```